# is ubuntu phone (or tablet) use X for display server?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, xserver

is ubuntu phone (or tablet) use X for display server?
if so, it should change the Ubuntu Desktop Application to Ubuntu Phone (or tablet) its much easier for developers.

if not, what Display Server is used?

Answer (score 0):

I watched Jono Bacon talk answer a question about this on a ubuntuonair webcast, just a couple of weeks ago. As far as i can remember he said that it used the same server as Android. They are not going to use x (and neither would it be wayland). bit of a shock that:) To see what he had to say exactly you would have to watch the webcast. Ubuntu On Air has a channel on youtube
Cheers

Comment: found it :)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkeiz0BlSEM&feature=plcp
watch from 34 mins.